# Combobox in NetBeans IDE will not populate with extracted year from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

I have a MySQL table for quotes with the column name `quote_date`which stores the date of when the quote was issued. I want to take just the year of that date to populate a combobox in my Netbeans application. The SQL syntax I used to get the year was:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM quote_date) AS quoteYear from quotesdb
```

This syntax works on MySQL but on Netbeans the combobox remains empty. There are no errors that occur. What could be wrong?

Here is how I implemented the syntax in Netbeans:

```
try
 {
     String sql = "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM quote_date) AS quoteYear from quotesdb";
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //connection for database
    Connection conn = (Connection)
            //root and username and password for access to the database
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salventri","root","password");
    //create the statement that will be used
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 

    while(rs.next())
    {
        String year = rs.getString("quote_date");
        //adding the quote year to the combobox
        cboQIYear.addItem(year);
    }
```

Comment: Hard coded data in the database?

Comment: So basically hard code the years into the combo box?

Comment: I worked it out. It was such a stupid syntax typo I missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was not populating the combo box was that in the initial line:

```
String sql = "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM quote_date) AS quoteYear from quotesdb";
```

I was suppose to get the year from `quoteYear`but instead I did not change the column name in the line:

```
String year = rs.getString("quote_date");
```

Once I changed `rs.getString("quote_date");` to `rs.getString("quoteYear");` the combo box was populated with the years

Comment: *"There are no errors that occur."* I had suspected that was because the `catch` was suppressing output..  That was the reason I suggested posting a [mcve]!  ;)  Ensure *every* catch has at least (unless logging is implemented) a call to `printStackTrace()` ..  Good call on writing up an answer.  :)